# Удаление графического интерфейса Gnome

Tags: linux, windows, gui, консоль, gnome

У меня стоит VMBitrix7.4-3CentOS7.7-x86_64 .  Каким образом удалить графический интерфейс Gnome из терминала (я не нашел удаление именно для моей ОС )?

Answer (score 0):

`yum groupremove 'X Window System' 'GNOME'`

не забываем предварительно отредактировать `/etc/inittab`

Comment: а что в `etc/inittab` надо отредактировать?

Comment: Что произойдет, когда будет удален гном, что надо предварительно отредактировать `/etc/ inittab`?

Comment: Скорей всего у тебя так. id:5:initdefault:
Нужно поменять 5 на 3 что бы после рестарта загрузился shell